# Rails 3 scope query

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model named "SessRequest", which contains fields "sess_start" (start datetime of session) and "sess_duration" (session duration in hours). So, end time of a session is: sess_start + sess_duration.hours
I need to filter out all sessions whose "end_time" is behind current time. 
For this the corresponding model scope looks like following:

```
SESSION_ASSUMED_PAST_AFTER_HRS = 3
  scope :past,
    lambda{where('(sess_start < :current_time) AND (sess_start IS NOT NULL)', :current_time => 0.days.from_now - SESSION_ASSUMED_PAST_AFTER_HRS.hours)};
```

I want to make this scope based on "sess_duration" database field rather than constant SESSION_ASSUMED_PAST_AFTER_HRS. 
How can this be done while still keeping it database agnostic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem for creating complex SQL queries and various RDBMS systems.

Your code will looks like:

```
SESSION_ASSUMED_PAST_AFTER_HRS = 3
scope :past, where { (sess_start < SESSION_ASSUMED_PAST_AFTER_HRS.hours.ago) & (sess_start != nil ) }
```

Comment: but, I need to use filed "sess_duration" of the same table, instead of the constant SESSION_ASSUMED_PAST_AFTER_HRS.

Comment: Is there any standard way of doing it without using any external gem?

Comment: Probably you can't do that with keeping database agnostic